# Performance: calling a method recursively vs. using conditional logic

Tags: java, performance

I call a method with a variable `x`, I make some checks and if some conditions are true I have to execute part of the same method with a different variable value.

What is more effective?

1. to call the method again (recursion), or
2. to change the value of my variable and leave the program to execute the following lines of the method?

In both cases i can make it work but what is the more efficient way?

For the second case, I use an `if` statement on top. I read the value I want and then the following if statements are executed using this value.

```
public void mymethod(x){
    if (con){
        x = something;
    }
    if (con2){
        //do something
    } else if(con3) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about some sort of micro-optimization, which is useless. Do whatever makes more sense.

Comment: anna, I suppose 'anadromic' is the Greek word for 'recursion'?

Comment: micro optimization is for compilers, readability is for programmers. do whatever is more readable.

Comment: Don't worry about efficiency.  That would be premature optimization.  Code for clarity first and foremost until you know you have a performance problem.

Comment: Please consider giving some thought to the formatting of your questions. That was particularly difficult to read before the two separate edits that cleaned it up.

Comment: @MikeNakis recursion is what i mean. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is more efficient to modify the value of *x* and continue the method execution. The reason is simple. When you call a function, the caller state must be saved (into a stack) then local variables of the called method are read and so the called method is executed. So, being already in the called method *myMethod* it'd be "cheaper" to access the variable *x* to modify its value and then continue

Comment: Actually, if the method is a hotspot there's a pretty good chance the HotSpot compiler will inline it, meaning it won't have to create a stack frame at all.  Which is why it's not constructive to micro-optimize on a JVM language.

Comment: Please note that this is only correct for Java. Other languages detect tail-recursion, and recycle the stack frame for the new method call.

Answer (score 4):

As Dave said, you probably should not be concerned at all about such micro-optimizations. The best thing to do is to write your code in such a way that it is easiest to read and understand. The best approach in my opinion would be to move the "do something" part into a separate function, and pass to it all the parameters that it needs in order to do its job.

If you really want to get down to efficiency talk, be advised that modern systems tend to rely heavily on caching, so many approaches to performance which used to work in the past do not actually constitute improvements anymore. On the contrary, they worsen things.

Comment: True, and the best part is that HotSpot typically optimizes better for programs written by developers trying to be correct and clean rather than clever.